# Modelling Composite Entity

Tags: data-modeling

I have 4 entities - BusinessEntity, ParentEntity, ChildAEntity and ChildBEntity. Both ChildAEntity and ChildBEntity are derived from the ParentEntity and they are used in different contexts. For BusinessEntity, it should represent both ChildAEntity and ChildBEntity. However, in the context of BusinessEntity, some properties in ChildAEntity and ChildBEntity need to have the same value. My questions is which is better approach..or none of them are good at all..

Option-1
Create BusinessEntity with two properties of type ChildAEntity and ChildBEntity. Ensure those properties, that need to have the same value, have the same value.

Option-2
Create new ChildAEntity and ChildBEntity and leave out those properties that need to have the same value. Put those shared properties in the BusinessEntity.

Option-3
Similar to Option-1 except the shared properties that need to have the same value will be refactored into the BusinessEntity.

They all have their downsides and I can't think of better way.